Efficiently listing files older than 3 years on a large disk with millions of files
I have to implement a system to archive files that have been more than 3 years on a 35TB disk, millions of files.
How can I implement an efficient way to list the files that are older than 3 years?  Is there anything to index files' metadata in Linux?
This could be done using
find /directory/path -type f -mtime +$((3 * 365))

but this is really, really painfully slow!

A file's "age" (mtime and ctime) are kept in the file's inode, Searching (reading) "millions" of file's inodes is going to take time.  Also reread man find, you need -mtime +10000 to find ages greater than 10000. -mtime 10000 finds ages exactly 10000 days old.

You might be better off to maintain a separate database of file metadata, and pay the cost of populating that database once a year (analogous to your find).  Then, at whatever cadence you need, you can consult the database for files that would be more than 3 years old, and archive them if they still exist.

Similar: Indexing files' metadata

Are all the files in a single directory, or do you have a hierarchy? Indexing the files is a small part of the problem, as find reads the directory in stored order: actually moving the files searches the whole directory for every file name (efficiency depends on the file system type). Also, 10000 is 27 years -- you may not find any files from that.

@Paul_Pedant Effectively I didi not count yet the number of file, but some colleage have waited up to 24h of find.  So it is really a lot of them...

Can you run the find on (say) a daily basis and then have people use its results? Obviously you'll not get totally uptodate accuracy but you will get speed

@Chris : You might get look-up speed from a reference file, but (on many file systems), referencing the actual file by filename will still search the directory linearly, on average reading 50% of entries before getting the hit. I believe the first move should be to hard-link the files (in batches of maybe 10,000) into a new directory structure (hard-link because soft-link will still search the original huge directory by name). Then index the names to their batch so you can search two short directories instead of one huge one.

@Paul_Pedant I was thinking in terms of locate, where the files are indexed periodically (find /whatever -type f -mtime +"$days") and the results are displayed on demand at almost zero cost (cat /some/resultsfile.txt)

@Chris : Of course, I understand locate will spit out selected names of files you may have. But find is taking 24 hours to scan the directory. If you want to read, move, copy or even delete one specific file, accessing it by name might take (on average, on some file systems) 12 hours to open that file, because it has to search that same huge directory all over again. I'm proposing to add a 2-  or 3-level alternative naming scheme. And also, any additional files from now on should be incrementally added to that naming scheme, not require a frequent full re-indexing.

@Chris : (cont) In fact, as new files are appended to the directory, and likely are of most interest, many open-by-name events might skew that average significantly towards 24 hours. I would prefer to re-group files by YYYYMM (or even YYYYMM/YYYYMMDD) as soon as this huge single directory has been tamed. 10M files over ten years is 3000 per day, one per 30 secs. It would be good to just have a rough count of files (e.g. if they have their own partition, an inode count df -i), and any existing naming convention (if you have 10 million files, something avoids name clashes).

@MUYBelgium : It would be helpful just to run a find ... | wc to establish an order of magnitude of the problem. Or even just some heuristic like "We have been making a file a minute for the last 16 years". "OK, that around 10 million". The system is clearly unusable at present (and has been for 90% of its life), and presumably you don't have backups for it either. Listing or Indexing the files is one thing, "archiving" is quite another. Does that mean removing, compressing, writing to tape, or what? If you don't define the ultimate target, you won't know what initial steps are useful.

@Paul_Pedant I wouldn't put millions of files in just one directory either. (And indeed for a project in a previous job where we were collecting hundreds of photos daily and needing to keep them for several years, we intentionally avoided doing so, for avoidance of the issues described here.)

If "find is taking 24 hts to scan the directory", I'd check the system logs for disk complaints (page through sudo journalctl /dev/sdXX (/dev/sdXX is the device name, or sudo less /var/log/messages), check how it's mounted (mount), maybe run a disk performance check (bonnie++, http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie). Does your system have swap space? (free will tell you). [Edit] your Question to add information. Do nou use Add Comment.

What is the overall goal?  Knowing the purpose could really help with a solution.  Say you have a directory listing of files 3 years and older, what do you want to do with them?

Knowing what these files purpose are would significantly help find a solution.
But, for an example of such, I have a script that I use to create .metadata files, in JSON, for a directory, recursively.  It assumes you have a folder, such as ~/database, and in this folder you put the directory you want a metadata index of.
It's currently using ./db1_data/ for ease of expanding the directory to ./db2_data/ and so on.
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

file_list=( ./db1_data/**/* )
meta_dir="./db1_meta"
generation_date=$(date +'%m-%d-%Y at %H:%M:%S')

clear -x
echo -e "\nGenerating JSON metadata\nPlease wait...\n"

if [ ! -d "$meta_dir" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$meta_dir"
    echo "Directory created: $meta_dir"
fi

for file_path in "${file_list[@]}"; do
    if [[ -f "$file_path" ]]; then
        base_name="${file_path##*/}"
                base_name_without_ext="${base_name%.*}"
        meta_file="$meta_dir/.$base_name_without_ext.metadata"

        if [ -e "$meta_file" ]; then
            echo -e "Files already exist. Exiting...\n" && exit 0
        else
            exiftool -json -All -g -Sort -struct -zip -mPt "$file_path" > "$meta_file" 2>> exif_stderr.log
            echo -e "\nGenerated: $generation_date CST" >> "$meta_file"
        fi
    fi
done

[ -s exif_stderr.log ] && echo -e "\nFinished with error(s): exif_stderr.log." || rm ./exif_stderr.log; echo -e "Metadata generated successfully.\n"

exit 0

From here, there's a lot of possibilities.
